# Transactions with bluetooth device on Ipad

Tags: javascript, ios, angular, ionic-framework, ipad

I have a question about bluetooth devices. I connected a bluetooth barcode scanner to Ipad. I opened notepad and scanned barcodes with the bluetooth device. Everything happened successfully.

I want to do operations with keyboard while the bluetooth device is connected. But I always click three dots at the bottom of the screen to open the keyboard and then click 'Show Keyboard'. This is how I open the keyboard. I always want the keyboard to open without doing these operations.

Is there a method to this? (or code, function) Do I always have to do these steps when the bluetooth device is connected?

Comment: You have to do it manually unless the Bluetooth scanner has a "show keyboard"  button. Some do

Comment: I am using this device.
https://www.amazon.co.uk/Datalogic-DBT6420-BK-BTK1-DBT6420-POCKET-IMAGER-Black/dp/B07CCBMH19

I didnt see keyboard button. So I have to do steps manually from Ipad, right? It is a bit of a hassle when using the device with these steps.

Comment: Yes. That is the trade off when using these sorts of scanners with iPads. The good part is no programming is required. The bad part is it isn't easy to combine scanning with other keyboard entry

Comment: Some things to try here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/295088/how-to-bring-up-the-virtual-keyboard-on-ios-when-a-bluetooth-keyboard-is-connect#:~:text=Go%20to%20Settings%20%3E%20Accessibility%20%3E%20Keyboards,bring%20up%20the%20keyboard%20options.